# Why does Eclipse show incomplete Scala classes in the Outline view?

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

Context: Scala project with imported library such as akka-http.

IDE: Eclipse (mars) + Scala-IDE 4.3

OS: Windows

I've configured `sbt` to download source code related to dependent projects, so I can view/inspect libraries more fully.

When I bring up `akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive` I see only the first few members of that class in the Outline view.  I can see additional members in the code that are not displayed in the Outline.

Why am I not seeing the full outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Right click on the project to open `Properties` -> `Resource` -> `Text file encoding`, and set to `UTF-8`.

This can also be set for the workspace properties; it's not clear to me if changing the workspace properties auto-sets existing projects, I'm guess it doesn't.

#### Why?

Admittedly a guess, but...

The problem seems to be associated with the combination of Scala IDE 4.3 (for Eclipse), Windows, and assumptions about source files and text encodings:

- The [Eclipse Scala-IDE 4.3](http://scala-ide.org/blog/release-notes-4.3.0-vfinal.html) has a new Outline view, which seems to render a better representation of Scala classes by deferring to source.  And it fails to do that properly when it doesn't grok the text encoding.
- In Eclipse the default text file encoding is "Inherited from container" for the workspace.  I presume existing projects inherit that setting from the workspace.
- The Windows text file encoding (the container mentioned previously) is ISO-8859-1, or possibly something else... but not UTF-8.
- In my problem Outline view, it turns out that the last member displayed for a class contains a unicode '⇒' (syntactically equivalent to '=>' in Scala).
- silent boom